# JQuery enabling the control is not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript

I have a Div inside this I have disable all controls except on control.I am disabling whole div and I am trying to enable back the specific control

```
$('#TestInfo').children().attr('disabled',true);
$('#ddstatus').prop('disabled',f‌​alse)
```

This works in google chrome but in Internet explorer it is still showing as disabled. I tried all possible to enable like removeAttr, removeProp nothing worked. Any help on this is highly appreciated. –

Comment: Why are you using `.attr('disabled',true)` the first time? `.prop` is the correct method to use.

Comment: Post a complete code example please. Also, what versions of IE and jQuery are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Afaik, IE interprets the existence of the disabled attribute, not its value. Remove the attribute completely and it should be ok.

You can use removeAttr to do this (https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/).

```
$('#ddstatus').removeAttr("disabled");
```